# Programmatically capture events (on a view) in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, events

I am using a third party library (Three20) which generates views from code, not in a nib.

I can get hold of the UIView but of the control, but obviously this doesnt derive from UIControl.

So how could I capture a touch event on the view? Usually I would just put a transparent button over the view in the nib and hook up the event to that, but that isn't really possible here.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Since `UIView` inherits from `UIResponder`, you can create a new subclass of `UIView` and use that instead, overriding only the touch-related methods:

```
–touchesBegan:withEvent:
–touchesMoved:withEvent:
–touchesEnded:withEvent:
–touchesCancelled:withEvent:
```

Also be sure to read the [Event Handling Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html).